# Prove $G^{+\rho(\mu}H^{+\nu)}{}_{\rho} = -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu \nu}G^{+\rho \sigma}H^+_{\rho \sigma}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

> I want to prove the following fact for two antisymmetric tensors:
>   $$ 
> G^{+\rho (\mu} H^{+\nu)}{}_{ \rho} = -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu \nu} G^{+\rho \sigma}H_{\rho \sigma}^{+}. \tag{4.39}$$

(See e.g. Freedman & van Proeyen, *Supergravity,* 2012.)

When I try to do it I get
\begin{align}
2G^{+\rho (\mu} H_{\,\,\, \rho}^{+\nu)} &= G^{+\rho \mu}H_{\,\, \rho}^{+\nu} +  G^{+\rho \nu}H_{\,\, \rho}^{+\mu} \\
&= G^{+\rho \mu}H_{\sigma \rho}^{+}\eta^{\sigma \nu} + G^{+\rho \nu}H_{\sigma \rho}^{+}\eta^{\sigma \mu}
\end{align}
but after that nothing I try seems to work out. Any tips please?

**Update**: I have to include the following information

$$H_{\mu \nu}^{+} = \frac{1}{2}(H_{\mu \nu} + \tilde{H}_{\mu \nu} ).\tag{4.36}$$

Of course $\tilde{H}_{\mu \nu} $ is the dual tensor defined as
$$\tilde{H}^{\mu \nu}  = -\frac{1}{2} i\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}H_{\rho \sigma}. $$
A hint to solve this problem is to first prove 
$$ \tilde{G}^{\rho \mu} \tilde{H}^{\mu}{}_{\rho}  = -\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu \nu}G^{\rho \sigma}H_{\rho \sigma} - G^{\rho \nu}H^{\mu}{}_{\rho}. \tag{4.40}$$

Comment: Given that you are using $\eta^{\mu\nu}$, is this in Minkowski space?

Comment: I have made a typo which I have correceted. Indeed it is Minkowski.

Comment: Since both sides are bilinear in $G,H$, what if you check the proposed identity for a simple antisymmetric tensor, $G^{\rho\mu} = x^\rho y^\mu - x^\mu y^\rho$, similar for $H^{\nu\rho}$? (I think this will show that the proposed identity *does not* hold...)

Comment: Is there any other information about $G$ or $H$? They are just antisymmetric?

Comment: Υes, I apologize for not including it since I thought this was something general about anti-symmetric tensors. I am editing the question.

Comment: Just write Levi-Civita contractions as the generalized Kronecker delta. I mean something like this $\epsilon^{ijk} \epsilon_{imn}=\delta^j_m \delta^k_n -\delta^j_n \delta^k_m$. This would be the key. The other steps are routine.

Comment: Indeed, but seems to be way too complicated. If one tries to follow the hint you have something like $\delta_{\nu \sigma \kappa \lambda}^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}$ and I am not sure if I should do this massive expansion.

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): There is in general no reason why the anticommutator $\{A,B\}_+$ of two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ should only have a trace-part $\frac{2}{n}{\rm tr}(AB)~{\bf 1}_{n\times n}$ and no traceless symmetric part. (There is a corresponding representation-theoretic formulation in terms of fusion rules.)

Comment: @Qmechanic I am not sure what you want to say. The question I have posted is about some specific tensors. I can let you know where to find the specific problem.

Comment: why is there an "of couse" before your definition of the dual tensor?

Comment: This is how the dual tensor is defined.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the definition you give is correct. Do you have a reference? Usually I see it defined without the factor of $i$.

Comment: Yes, of course, you can also define it without it as well (I think with a sign change). Check Freedman and Van Proyen's book "Supergravity" notes of the Amsterdam-Brussels-Paris doctoral school.

Comment: The title "Confusion with antisymmetric tensors!" was much to broad given the very specific nature of this question. I edited it. Please make question titles as specific as possible, as indicated by the helpful text which shows up in the box into which you type the title.

Comment: Ok, I did not know I could put so specific titles. Will do next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\G}{\mathbf{G}}
\newcommand{\H}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\tH}{\tilde{\H}}
\newcommand{\tG}{\tilde{\G}}
\newcommand{\Hp}{\H^+}
\newcommand{\Gp}{\G^+}$I will prove the answer two ways. The first way is the way you were "supposed" to do it, and the second way is another way of doing it.

## The way you were supposed to do it

First let me define some notation to hopefully make things easier to read. Let's define $\A \bullet \B$ to be the tensor whose $\mu,\nu$ components are given by $A^{\rho \mu}B^\nu{}_\rho$. Also, let's define $A:B$ to be the tensor $\boldsymbol{\eta} A^{\mu \nu} B_{\mu\nu}$. Notice both these products are bilnear. Also if $\A$ has componets $A^{\mu \nu}$, then let $\A ^T$ be the tensor with components $A^{\nu \mu}$.

Then we must show $\Gp \bullet \Hp + (\Gp \bullet \Hp)^T = -\frac{1}{4} \Gp : \Hp$.
We will do this in two steps. First we will show how this can be deduced from the hint, then we will show how to prove the hint.

Let us start by plugging in the definition of $\Gp$ and $\Hp$ into the left hand side. The identity becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}&\frac{1}{4}\left(\left(\G + \tG\right)\bullet\left(\H+\tH\right)+\left(\left(\G + \tG\right)\bullet\left(\H+\tH\right)\right){}^T  \right) \\= &-\frac{1}{16}\left(\G + \tG\right):\left(\H + \tH\right)
\end{aligned}$$.

Using bilinearity and rearranging the left hand side, we can put it in the form 
$$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{4} \left(\tG \bullet \tH + (\G \bullet \H)^T\right)+\frac{1}{4} \left(\G \bullet \tH + (\tG \bullet \H)^T\right) \\
+&\frac{1}{4} \left(\tG \bullet \H + (\G \bullet \tH)^T\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\G \bullet \H + (\tG \bullet \tH)^T\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

But now the hint tells us that

$\begin{equation}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\tG \bullet \tH + (\G \bullet \H)^T = -\frac{1}{2} \G : \H,
\end{equation}$

from which, since the dual of the dual is the same tensor, we can deduce

$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\G \bullet \tH + (\tG \bullet \H)^T &= -\frac{1}{2} \tG : \H,\\
  \tG \bullet \H + (\G \bullet \tH)^T &= -\frac{1}{2} \G : \tH,\\
 \G \bullet \H + (\tG \bullet \tH)^T &= -\frac{1}{2} \tG : \tH.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$.

Therefore the left hand side becomes $-\frac{1}{8} \left(\G : \H+ \tG : \H+ \G : \tH+ \tG : \tH\right)$. On the other hand, this is what we get when we use bilinearity to expand the right hand side (up to a factor of two).

Lastly, we just have to prove the hint. We have

$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde{G}^{\rho \mu} \tilde{H}_{\nu\rho}=& -\frac{1}{4} \delta^{\rho \mu \alpha \beta}_{\nu\rho\sigma\gamma}G_{\alpha\beta}H^{\sigma\gamma} \\
=& \frac{1}{4} \delta^{\rho \mu \alpha \beta}_{\rho\nu\sigma\gamma}G_{\alpha\beta}H^{\sigma\gamma} \\
=& -\frac{3!}{4} \eta^{[\mu}{}_\nu\eta^\alpha{}_\sigma\eta^{\beta]}{}_\gamma G_{\alpha\beta}H^{\sigma\gamma} \\
=& -\frac{1}{2} \eta^\mu{}_\nu G_{\sigma\gamma}H^{\sigma\gamma}  -\frac{1}{2} G_{\gamma\nu}H^{\mu\gamma} - \frac{1}{2} G_{\nu\sigma}H^{\sigma\mu} \\
=& -\frac{1}{2} \eta^\mu{}_\nu G_{\sigma\gamma}H^{\sigma\gamma}  -\frac{1}{2} G_{\gamma\nu}H^{\mu\gamma} - \frac{1}{2} G_{\sigma\nu}H^{\mu\sigma} \\
=& -\frac{1}{2} \eta^\mu{}_\nu G_{\sigma\gamma}H^{\sigma\gamma} - G_{\sigma\nu}H^{\mu\sigma}.
\end{aligned}$$

The third equality is true by properties of the generalized kronecker delta (the minus sign is because $\det \eta = -1$). The fourth equality holds because $G_{\alpha \beta}$ is already antisymmetric in $\alpha \beta$, so we need only consider cyclic permutations of $\mu \alpha \beta$.

## Another way to get the answer

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbf{F}}
\newcommand{\Fp}{\F^+}
\newcommand{\e}{\mathbf{e}}
\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\g}{\mathbf{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathbf{h}}$
Recall that an arbitrary four space-time dimensional antisymmetric tensor $\F$ can have its components $F^{\mu \nu}$ written in block matrix form as

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\e^T   \\
\e &  \b^\times
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $\b^\times$ is an antisymmetric matrix satisfying that for any $\mathbf{v}$, $\b^\times \mathbf{v} = \b \times \mathbf{v}$. In other words $(\b^\times)_{ik} = \epsilon_{ijk} b_j$. Now notice that

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{v}^T \b^\times &= (-\b^\times\mathbf{v})^T \\
&=  (-\b \times\mathbf{v})^T\\
&= (\mathbf{v} \times\b)^T.
\end{aligned}$$

Also

$$
\begin{aligned}
\b^\times \b'^{\times} \mathbf{v} &= \b \times (\b' \times \mathbf{v}) \\
&= \b' (\b \cdot \mathbf{v}) - \mathbf{v} (\b' \cdot \b),
\end{aligned}
$$

so that $$\b^\times \b'^{\times} = \b' \otimes \b - \b' \cdot \b.$$

Now let's find $\Fp$. As you have defined it, $\Fp$ has coordinates given by

$$F^+{}^{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(\e+i\b)^T   \\
\e+i\b &  (\b-i\e)^\times
\end{pmatrix},$$

Thus we see for an arbitrary antisymmetric tensor $\F$, we can write $\Fp$ in the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\mathbf{f}^T   \\
\mathbf{f} &  -i\mathbf{f}^\times
\end{pmatrix}.$$

In particular, we may right 
$\G = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\g^T   \\
\g &  -i\g^\times
\end{pmatrix}$,
and $\H = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\h^T   \\
\h &  -i\h^\times
\end{pmatrix}.$

Now we wish to find the components of $G^{+\rho \mu} H^{+\nu}{}_\rho$. But this is just the transpose of the matrix product $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \h^T   \\
\h &  i\h^\times
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\g^T   \\
\g &  -i\g^\times
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
\h \cdot \g & -i (\h \times \g)^T   \\
i\h \times \g &  -\h \otimes \g + \g \otimes \h - \g \cdot \h 
\end{pmatrix}$$
If we symmetrize this we get $\begin{pmatrix}
\g \cdot \h & \mathbf{0}^T   \\
\mathbf{0} &  - \g \cdot \h 
\end{pmatrix} =  \g \cdot \h \eta^{\mu\nu}$.

Now that we have symmetrized $G^{+\rho \mu} H^{+\nu}{}_\rho$, we can get that $$2G^{+\rho (\mu} H^{+\nu)}{}_\rho=2\g \cdot \h \eta^{\mu\nu}.$$ Meanwhile it is easily seen that $$-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{+\mu \nu} G^{+\rho \sigma} H^+{}_{\rho \sigma}= \g \cdot \h \eta^{\mu \nu}.$$ Thus we have equality, except, again, the left hand side is too big by a factor of two.

Comment: yes, in my very first equation I should not have this 2.

Comment: I think you have some error in the indices in the proof of the hint. The third line from the end and the second line from the end should have some indices rearranged.

Comment: @Marion It is correct the way I have it. I got the third to last line by cyclically permuting to the right the top indices in the fourth to last line.